# Conditional rendering in <td> for respective row when a button in that row is clicked

Tags: reactjs, use-state, conditional-rendering

I want to implement a functionality where I can render the values of array and when I click on update for a particular record, conditional rendering should happen for some td's.
I have implemented this logic but it's not working as expected.

```
const [changeElementsOnUpdate, setChangeElementsOnUpdate] = useState(-1);
```

Have also written setState code for user object and users array

Here is the logic which I have written inside **tr** tag

```
<tr>
    <td>{users[0].prn}</td>
    <td>{users[0].name}</td>
    <td>{users[0].gender}</td>
                
    <td>
        {
            changeElementsOnUpdate === 0 ? 
                <select name="dept" value={user.dept} onChange={onInputChange}>
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
                    <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
                    <option value="ENTC">ENTC</option>
                    <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
                </select>
                : users[0].dept
        }
    </td>
            
    // subsequent td's
               
    <td>
        {
            changeElementsOnUpdate === 0 ?
                <input type="button" id={0} value="Done"
                    onClick={e =>  {
                        onUpdateSubmit(e);
                    }}
                />
                :
                <input type="button" id={0} value="Update"
                    onClick={(e) => {
                          setChangeElementsOnUpdate(e.target.id);
                    }}
                />
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to pass **id** to **setChangeElementsOnUpdate** so that the conditional rendering will happen only for that row and not for others.
Suppose if I click for second row then it will do setChangeElementsOnUpdate(1).
But for the above logic when I click on **update** button nothing is changing.

Can you please tell me what's going wrong and how can I get the required result.

Comment: I think `e.target.id` will give a string, but you're testing if it's a number `changeElementsOnUpdate === 0`. You can convert the `target.id` to a number or use `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasG2201. I just forgot this thing and thought something wrong with setState logic.